# Useable free wifi in Melbourne?

Tags: wifi, melbourne

I've been in the city about a day, and like many  Australian or New Zealand cities, free wifi is hard to find.  The hostel charged, and even McDonalds and Starbucks limit the access.  I've got quite a bit of work to do online, job hunting, mailing off CVs, apartment searching, and as a result the 30 min limits around the place don't really work for me - that'd be a LOT of coffees to buy!

I've found Gloria Jean Coffee seems to let you sit around and use theirs, but they aren't everywhere and I don't want to spend all day every day on their internet.  Are there other shops that allow free wifi in the downtown / CBD area?

Comment: Did you try the library?

Comment: Buy a 3G stick for $50. More reliable and you don't have to walk across town each time to get internet access...

Comment: @iHaveacomputer but I like getting my coffees ;) Good point tho, and it's something I'm considering as the friend's place I'm staying at doesn't have internet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, first of all [there is a list of restaurants](http://www.urbanspoon.com/tn/219/14/46322/Melbourne/Free-Wi-Fi/Downtown-Melbourne-restaurants) apart from the big chains which offer free Wifi as long as you consume something. Obviously you will have to make sure that these places are open and according to your taste. A cafe or pub might be more suitable than a sushi restaurant for long-term surfing.

Second of all there is a [HUGE list of places](http://www.onlymelbourne.com.au/melbourne_details.php?id=10425) with free wifi, and this list is maintained by an online magazine and much more detailed.

Answer (score 3):

After exploring for a few days, I've found some options.

- Many local coffee shops offer free wifi, often as part of a 'complete a survey, get free wifi' deal.
- The Gloria Jeans Coffee chain has free wifi.
- Flinders Street Coffee has an Internode free wifi option, which I suspect is in several places.
- Melbourne Central station and food court has free wifi.
- the State Library and other libraries have free wifi.
- Federation Square and the information center also has free wifi.